# Countinouly decrease the value on long click in recylerview adapter class

Tags: onlongclicklistener

Below is the code session. please check and solve my issue.

```
    holder.outer_qty.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
    private Handler mHandler = new Handler();
    private Runnable incrementRunnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override public void run() {
            mHandler.removeCallbacks(incrementRunnable);
            if (holder.outer_qty.isPressed()) {
                if (holder.outer_count > 1) {
                    Fragment_cataloguesall.mselected_update = 1;
                    holder.outer_count = holder.outer_count - 1;
                    holder.Total_outerQTY = holder.outerqntyValue * holder.outer_count;
                    holder.Total_qty.setText(Integer.toString(holder.Total_outerQTY));
                    Fragment_cataloguesall.dbcustom_list_vertical.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    helper.update_allpro(holder.productCode.getText().toString(), holder.plus_sign.getText().toString(), holder.outer_qty.getText().toString(), holder.Total_qty.getText().toString(), String.valueOf(holder.outer_count), "0");
                    holder.outer_count++;
                    dbList.clear();
                    mFilteredList.clear();
                    dbList = helper.GetProductData(Fragment_cataloguesall.CatCode, Fragment_cataloguesall.SubcatCode, "", Filter_screen);
                    mFilteredList = dbList;
                    selectedCard = dbList;
                } else {}
                mHandler.postDelayed(incrementRunnable, 1);
            }
        }
    };
    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
        mHandler.postDelayed(incrementRunnable, 1);
        return true;
    }
});
```

> How to solve this issue please explain or help me to solve it?

Comment: Please explain what you want to solve from this question.

Comment: On long click i want to decrease the value countinuously